# How to get the view which triggered the event in Android?

Tags: android

Do you know how can I get the view which triggered an event? 
 By example:

```
    final AutoCompleteTextView edtxInput = (AutoCompleteTextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.edtx_input);  
    edtxInput.setThreshold(2);
    edtxInput.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            Console.debug(TAG, "view: " + arg1, Console.Liviu);             
            edtxInput.setText(((FormOption)edtxInput.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getDescription());
        }
    });
```

The problem here is that I don't know how I can update the text from edtxInput in OnItemClickListener without making it final.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

> Parameters
>
> parent    The AdapterView where the click happened.

arg1 is the  AutoCompleteTextView (edtxInput) itself. so you can do

```
 AutoCompleteTextView edtxInput = (AutoCompleteTextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.edtx_input);  
    edtxInput.setThreshold(2);
    edtxInput.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            Console.debug(TAG, "view: " + arg1, Console.Liviu); 
AutoCompleteTextView medtxInput = (AutoCompleteTextView)parent;
                medtxInput.setText(((FormOption)medtxInput.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getDescription());
            }
        });
```

**UPDATE**

Seems like the `AutoCompleteTextView` is not a subclass of AdapterView. That is at some part "fault" of the SDK here. To get the `AutoCompleteTextView` you can do a hack

```
 AutoCompleteTextView medtxInput = (AutoCompleteTextView)view.getParent();
```

So you get the clicked view then get its parent that is the `AutoCompleteTextView`

But why you don't want `AutoCompleteTextView` to be final in the first place? Any particular reason?

If you want only the adapter you can write this and only this

```
((ChildClass)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getDescription();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know why is not possible to cast like this (AutoCompleteTextView)parent? Eclipse give me an error "Cannot cast from AdapterView<capture#1-of ?> to AutoCompleteTextView".

Comment: i'm sorry give me 5 mins to test it on my own and post the code correctly

Comment: I'm generating a form but this form can have an unknown number of autocomplete fields and if I will make every new AutoCompleteView final, I will have memory leaks. This is how my method looks: http://pastebin.com/2xEmPt1K.

Comment: AFAIK my solution will not solve your memory leaks problem. You are not creating a new view. You just get a reference of the same view (SAFE). Anyway keeping stuff in scope is always better

Comment: @weakwire : "AutoCompleteTextView medtxInput = (AutoCompleteTextView)view.getParent();" This throws an exception saying that "cannot cast form ListView to AutoCompleteTextView". It takes the parent of "view" as list view

Answer (score 0):

declare the edtxInput as global variable so that through out the class this variable is accessible.

Comment: that's even worse than declaring final

Answer (score 0):

Why making variable final is so bad for you? Any way you can make edtxInput global. See code below

```
public class myActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    AutoCompleteTextView mEditTextInput;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mEditTextInput = (AutoCompleteTextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.edtx_input);
        mEditTextInput.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        Console.debug(TAG, "view: " + arg1, Console.Liviu);             
        mEditTextInput.setText(((FormOption)mEditTextInput.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getDescription());
    }
}
```

Thats all.

Comment: I can't make it global because my application needs to be generic so the user should be able to add how many AutoCompleteTextViews he want in layout.